# PyCharm on Ubuntu shows different images and containers compare to what I see in the system. What causes this?

Tags: docker, pycharm

I have the latest professional version of PyCharm running it on Ubuntu.

So my project contains several containers and I deployed the project locally on my machine.

So checking with `docker ps` command and via **Docker Desktop** shows the same running containers.

But my PyCharm does not see images and containers displayed in the system. Also some strange images are displayed by PyCharm which are not visible in Docker Desktop. I tried to delete all images in PyCharm but this doesn't affect anyhow to system Docker.

I am connecting via unix docker socket to Docker daemon in PyCharm.

I tried to google for similar cases but couldn't find anything (like I am the only one facing this issue). I tried to uninstall docker from the system, IDE and install them back - didn't help. Also raised a ticket to JetBrains asking for help but still nobody has responded to me.

Docker Desktop containers:
[image: Docker Desktop containers]

PyCharm at the same time shows different images:
[image: PyCharm at the same time shows different images]

Answer (score 2):

It's because of Docker context. You can see them easily in VSCode > Docker tab.

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cS8T.png)

I guess it caused by installation of docoker-desktop, which points to
**"unix:///home//.docker/desktop/docker.sock"** meanwhile the default context points to **"unix:///var/run/docker.sock"**

So what you need to do is to change the context either in PyCharm or in docker-desktop. In PyCharm it's in Settings > Build, execution, deployment > Docker and then set the Engine API URL to **"unix:///home//.docker/desktop/docker.sock"**

Maybe the more clear solution would be to uninstall system docker and install only the docker-desktop. But it't up to you.